# Cannot Log Out of guest User

Tags: guest-account

Ever since I upgraded one of our schools student MacBook Airs to Mojave, logging out of the Guest User account is broken.  The cursor remains over a blank, black screen and nothing ever happens from there.  To get it back I need to force a shut down by holding down the power button.  I tried booting into Safe mode to see if that would help. It does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling SIP with 'csrutil disable' solved the problem for me, although that doesn't reflect well on Apple or MacOS.